# Tkinter Gui For Astar algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, list, button, tkinter, a-star

I'm trying to make the input maze of Astar algorithm(alogorithm to find the shortest path between start and destination and there can be some blockages within the maze,
which takes input a maze representing blockages only, as shown below).

From the GUI using the Click1 command in each button,
I intend to get an output like this(where I inserted a blockage at [3][2]).
1 represents blockage which is to avoided to find the path from start to end.

`[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`

but I get a output as following,I can't understand why it's blocking the same column of each and every row

`[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]`

I created the maze in the **init**(): of class App() using this:

```
def __init__(self, master,dimension,indexes):
   self.maze=[[0]*self.dimension]*self.dimension
```

this entire thing is within a class App():
for creating the grid of buttons, and storing their reference

```
        self.gid = []
        for i in range(self.dimension):
            row = []
            Grid.rowconfigure(self.frame1, i + 1, weight=3)
            for j in range(self.dimension):
                Grid.columnconfigure(self.frame1, j + 1, weight=3)
                btn=Button(self.frame1,command=lambda i=i, j=j: self.Click1(i, j))
                btn.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=2,pady=2,ipadx=1,ipady=1)
                row.append(btn)
                row[-1].grid(row=i + 1, column=j+1)
            self.gid.append(row)
```

the Click1 method/Command that also within this class:

```
    def Click1(self, i, j):
        self.indxes.append((i,j))
        if len(self.indxes)==1:
            self.gid[i][j]["bg"]="blue" #indicates start
        elif len(self.indxes)==2:
            self.gid[i][j]["bg"]="green" #indicates destinations
        else:
            self.gid[i][j]["bg"] = "black"
            self.maze[i][j] = 1  #how I insert blockage within the maze
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your init:

```
def __init__(self, master,dimension,indexes):
   self.maze = [[0] * self.dimension] for _ in range(self.dimension)]
```

The latter `* self.dimension` call was assigning the same reference to all your inner lists (dimension number of times) - meaning when one is changed all will change.

This creates a unique list for each sublist

Comment: Thank you this worked. Everything happens with class here, I forgot.

Comment: Glad to hear this helped, please consider accepting it so others in the future can find the answer quickly as well